# How to model a database structure with repeating fields in every table

Tags: database, model, structure

I'm in the process of structuring a databasemodel for my new project. For all the entities in my model (which is a cms, and the entities as such f.ex: page, content, menu, template and a bunch of others) they all have in common the same attributes on dates and names.

More specifically each entity contains the following for the dates: IsCreated, IsValidFrom, IsPublished, IsDeleted, IsEdited and IsExpired, and for names: CreatedByNameId, ValidFromByNameId, PublishedByNameId and so on...

I'm going to use EF5 for mapping to objects.

The question is as simple: What is the best way to structure this: Having all the fields in every table (which I am not obliged to...) or to have two separate tables which the other can relate to...?

Thanks in advance /Finn.

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow, as it is not a specific programming question and is opinion based (which is best...)

Comment: Well I think it could be a programming question, though! Maybe it would be possible to have all the repeated fields in one table i db, and then make a t4 template where the one table's mapped object could be a base class for the rest of the mapped objects...? Or am I way off in my thinking here...?

Comment: Maybee the title is a little bit misleading as I was presuming between the lines that this structure should be a "workable" structure in code as mapped objects...

Answer (score 0):

First of all - give this a read - http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html

You really need to think about your queries/access paths.  There are many tradeoffs between different implementations.

In reply to your example though,

Given the following setup:

### COMMON

ValidFromByNameId

### SPECIFIC1

FieldA

### SPECIFIC2

FieldB

Querying by the COMMON attributes is easy but you'll have to work some magic when pulling up the subclasses  (unless EF5 does it for you)

If the primary questions you're asking are about specific1 and specific2 then perhaps this isn't the right model.  having the COMMON table doesn't really buy you much necessary as it will introduce a join to load any Specific1 object.  In this case, i'd probably just have duplicate columns.

This answer is intentionally partial as a full answer is better handled by the numerous articles and blogs already out there.  Search for "mapping object hierarchies to databases"